# keyboard appear and view scroll to top

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll, keyboard

I have a problem in my code: when I tap on the UITextView and the keyboard is showing, there is a scroll to top (and I really don't know why !)
I have to scroll down myself to go back to the UITextView.

I'm in a tableView, and my cells have dynamic heights.

Here is a little demo of my problem:

[image]

I made some research and I tried this:

```
   @objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: NSNotification) {
      print("show")
      if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
         if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0{
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
         }
      }
   }

   @objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: NSNotification) {
      print("hide")
      if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
         if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0{
            self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
         }
      }
   }
```

It sitll doesn't work. That's really weird because that's the only view where I have this problem.

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: are you saying that your tableview is automatically get scroll when keyboard appears ?

Comment: Yes exactly @Lion !

Comment: are you using any library to handle keyboard like IQKeyboardManager or other?

Comment: No I don't ... Very strange...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reference to the textView, then try to add this code in your keyboardWillShow function.

```
scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(textView.frame, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you tap inside a `UITextView` it becomes the first responder and if you read the documentation it clearly states:

> ... Some system views, like table views, help you by scrolling the first responder into view automatically. ...

This is a built-in feature.

Anyhow, you can try to remove the keyboard observer from the `UITableView`.

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(tableView, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
```

[UITextView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview)

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar issues. when you scroll up and down then automatically call scrollViewWillBeginDragging method.

iOS use the UIScrollViewDelegate to determine the direction of the user's pan gesture.

Might be helpful to you following method.

**Swift 4**

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let translation: CGPoint = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: scrollView.superview)
    if translation.y > 0 {
        // react to dragging down
    }
    else {
        // react to dragging up
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

**Objective C**

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGPoint translation = [scrollView.panGestureRecognizer translationInView:scrollView.superview];

    if(translation.y > 0)
    {
         // react to dragging down

    } else
    {
         // react to dragging up
          [self.view endEditing:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to separate the cells.

In my situation, I had about 3 Textfields in a cell which spans out across the full view. So when clicking the textfield at the bottom of the view, I will get exactly the same behavior as you. ( I had a Collection View)

It turns out, it was scrolling back to the top of the cell (indexpath.row = 0). So I created a second cell (indexpath.row = 1) just containing the three textfields. Now it was scrolling the top of that cell (indexpath.row = 1) which was perfect.

I don't know what is the reason to that.